# write time on FTP server is very off

Tags: c++, datetime, filetime

im trying to compare file write times between a local file and a file on an ftp server. the file times on the local machine work and it makes sense, but when I look at the file on the ftp server it shows two different times, via windows explorer and rightclick->properties. I found out a hack that works and its commented in my code. Any help? I want the file times to relate to each other correctly. MFC, C++, Windows 7 32bit, VS 2008

Code:

```
            HINTERNET xmlHandle = NULL;
        WIN32_FIND_DATA ftpFileData;

        // find the file on the ftp server
        xmlHandle = FtpFindFirstFile( m_ftpHandle, _T("TPCFeed.xml"), &ftpFileData, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0 );
        if( NULL != xmlHandle )
        {
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // get the write time of the ftp file
            SYSTEMTIME ftpFileWriteTime,
                       stUTC1;
            FILETIME ftp;
            FileTimeToSystemTime( &ftpFileData.ftLastWriteTime, &stUTC1 );
            SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime( NULL, &stUTC1, &ftpFileWriteTime );

            // ----- HACK -------------------------------------------
            ftpFileWriteTime.wHour += 4; // this hack works
            SystemTimeToFileTime( &ftpFileWriteTime, &ftp );

            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // get the write time of the local file
            HANDLE localFileHandle = NULL;
            localFileHandle = CreateFile( _T(_XML_FILENAME_PATH), FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES,
                                     FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
                                     NULL, NULL );
            if( INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != localFileHandle )
            {
                // get local file time
                FILETIME localFileWriteTime,
                         local;
                GetFileTime( localFileHandle, NULL, NULL, &localFileWriteTime );

                SYSTEMTIME localFileWriteTime1,
                           stUTC;
                FileTimeToSystemTime( &localFileWriteTime, &stUTC );
                SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime( NULL, &stUTC, &localFileWriteTime1 );
                SystemTimeToFileTime( &localFileWriteTime1, &local );
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                int timeResult = CompareFileTime( &ftp, &local );
                if( -1 == timeResult )
                    AfxMessageBox( _T( "file on disk is later than ftp file, no need to download anything" ) );
                else if( 0 == timeResult )
                    AfxMessageBox( _T( "times are equal!" ) );
                else if( 1 == timeResult )
                    AfxMessageBox( _T( "file on ftp server is later than file on disk" ) );
```

Comment: How does the "hack" work? Your comment is not very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime( NULL, &stUTC1, &ftpFileWriteTime )

That doesn't work.  You'd have to pass the time zone in which the *server* lives, not your own time zone.  Assuming that the server even sends UTC time stamps, that wasn't common the last time I gave up on it.  Finding out what timezone it lives in ought to be challenging.  FTP hasn't matured well.

Comment: thanks for the post. I will try to find out where the server lives.